# Stop service in pause not in rotation

Tags: java, android, service

I have a `Service` in my application and I want stop it on pause application and start it again on resume.
if I write these codes in `onPause` and `onResume` method it works, but in rotation service stops and starts again. I want in rotation service don't stop and start again. How do I do this?

Comment: do it in onCreate / onDestroy then

Comment: in rotation this sequence occurs:onPause, onSaveInstanceState, onStop, onDestroy, onCreate, onStart, onRestoreInstanceState, onResume

Comment: indeed, sorry, use `isFinishing()` then in `onDestroy` and `Bundle savedInstanceState` parameter in `onCreate`